# How to scroll collapsing Toolbar and RecyclerView simultaneously?

Tags: android, toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout, android-design-library

As you can see in the Screenshots I have a transparent collapsing Toolbar which collapses on scrolling.

The problem is that the RecyclerView doesn't scroll while the Toolbar collapses.

How can i change this to collapse Toolbar and scroll RecyclerView simultaneously?

My layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                             android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                             android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"/>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:elevation="0dp"
    android:background="#28000000">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap|enterAlways">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The ViewPager contains a Fragment with a RecyclerView.

Before scrolling:
[image: Before scrolling]

Scrolling while Toolbar is visible:
[image: Scrolling while Toolbar is visible]

Scrolling while Toolbar is collapsed
[image: Scrolling while Toolbar is collapsed]

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                             android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                             android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">



<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:elevation="0dp"
    android:background="#28000000">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap|enterAlways">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! Unfortunately this doesn't work. The ViewPager / RecyclerView is now below the Toolbar (no overlapping).

Comment: remove app:layout_collapseMode="pin" from toolbar @Benny

Comment: Doesn't change anything